# Returning the oldest timestamp of a query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the time of the oldest timestamp in the MySQL table "comment" where the following conditions are met:

1. `Loginid` of timestamp is equal to `$uid`.
2. Timestamps were made within the last hour.

I have tried the code below and it echoes nothing for `$minutes`.

How can I get `$minutes` to echo the oldest timestamp that meets the two conditions above?

**EDIT:**  `datecommented` is a timestamp.

**EDIT 2:**  `$minutes` echoes out as a blank space.  Could this be a PHP formatting issue?

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM comment WHERE datecommented >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR AND loginid = "$uid" ORDER BY datecommented ASC LIMIT 1');

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$minutes = $row['datecommented'];


echo '<div>Test '.$uid.' test '.$minutes.' test.</div>';
```

Comment: What are you getting now? $minutes does not hold the correct date value?

Comment: Yes more data please, are you getting row results (at least one row?)

Comment: On `echo '<div>Test '.$uid.' test '.$minutes.' test.</div>';`, the `$uid` echoes out, but there is a blank space for `$minutes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please add error checking to your sql query, i suspect your sql is failing

```
 or die(mysql_error());
```

like this

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM comment WHERE datecommented >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR AND loginid = "$uid" ORDER BY datecommented ASC LIMIT 1') or die(mysql_error());
```

at a guess i would expect the " double quotes around "$uid" should be single quotes,
which means you need to change the single quotes around the whole statement to double quotes

like this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE datecommented >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR AND loginid = '$uid' ORDER BY datecommented ASC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: THanks, you're awesome.  It was the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You should first try your query on MySQL‘s command line or a tool such as PHPMyAdmin, then you will know if the data being returned is how you expect it.

I also suggest to use a `SELECT ... UNIX_TIMESTAMP(thefieldyouwantatimestampfrom) ... WHERE ...` in case the column is not storing or returning timestamps as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the "datecommented" is in unixtimestamp, then of course it doesn't return the minutes, but seconds. As the unixtimestamp is in seconds.

Does your mysql query even work like that? Or is the actual query problematic too?

Is your `$row` outputting anything? Try `print_r($row);`.

However simply put, my answer would be, that you are not converting your raw unxitimestamp into minutes.

You can get your seconds to minutes like this: `echo ($row['datecommented'] * 60);`

And you can get the minute value of your unixtimestamp like this: `echo date("i", $row['datecommented']);`